# Parent-child relationship modeling REST API

Tags: rest, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a sample table below with a parent-child relationship.

| id | parent |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | null |

I have to represent this in the UI as a tree structure. What is or are the best approaches to this? Do I fetch the data as flat from the API and restructure it as tree hierarchy at the front-end.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": null,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "parent": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "parent": 2,
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "parent": null,
    }
]
```

OR

The API should per-structure the response as a tree such that the UI simply consumes it.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "parent": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "parent": 2,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "parent": null,
        "children": []
    }
]
```

If I have to use something like the second approach, what is the most efficient way to do this such that there will not be duplicate entries.

I'm using djangorestframework and react.

Answer (score 0):

you can custom logic in serializer using serializers.SerializerMethodField()

**Model**

```
class FolderModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children', null=True)
```

**Serializer**

```
class FolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_children(self, obj):
    # Initialize a cache in the context if it doesn't exist
    if 'serialized_cache' not in self.context:
        self.context['serialized_cache'] = set()

    # Check if the object has already been serialized
    if obj.id in self.context['serialized_cache']:
        return []

    # Mark the object as serialized
    self.context['serialized_cache'].add(obj.id)

    # prevent deep recursion by set limit depth
    depth = self.context.get('depth', 0)
    if 10 > depth:
        self.context['depth'] = depth + 1
        return FolderSerializer(obj.children.all(), context=self.context, many=True).data
    else:
        return []

    class Meta:
        model = FolderModel
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'name', 'parent', 'children']
```

The implementation aims to showcase the use of context, allowing for flexibility according to your use case.

**view**

add filter `parent=None` into query set

```
class FolderView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = FolderModel
    queryset = FolderModel.objects.all().filter(parent=None)
    serializer_class = FolderSerializer
```

Anyway if you set '`queryset = FolderModel.objects.all().filter(parent=None)`' in view
there are no chance to hit 'Recursive Exceeded'. So you can just return serializer directly

```
def get_children(self, obj):
    return FolderSerializer(obj.children.all(), context=self.context, many=True).data
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't take care of object duplication during fetch. And it interest me more to know which of the approach is better. I guess in your opinion the second one is?

Comment: hello @Groot, Thank you for pointing this out and helping to refine my answer. Of course, you can utilize the context and pass it through every serializer to handle duplicate objects. I appreciate the opportunity to update my response based on this discussion.

Comment: but my main question remains unanswered :)

Comment: And your solution seems to have solved the duplication problem but strangely it still has duplicate object.